# Eclipse Maven Build/Plugin Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, maven

Did a fresh install of Eclipse 4.9, and can no longer build my Java project within Eclipse (still builds fine from command line).

The console output does not give me much to go on... just complains about the plugin...

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project myprojectcommon: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project myprojectcommon: Compilation failure
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:862)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I'm running Eclipse 4.9 on OSX High Sierra, w/ JDK 1.8_191. Maven version is 3.5.4, and Eclipse is configured to use this external Maven. JAVA_HOME and M2_HOME are set (though I don't think they are needed for OSX). I have tried building my existing workspace as well as importing the project into a fresh one.

Kind of at wit's end here... any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT 1: Then using a Terminal inside Eclipse, it does not recognize the mvn command, nor does it see any system variables like M2_HOME. Eclipse itself is configured to use my external maven installation, but I have also tried using the embedded. In both cases, Eclipse Terminal does not recognize mvn.

Comment: Have you try Project clean?

Comment: Can you post the pom.xml?

Comment: Have you tried <Alt>+<F5> on the project?

Comment: I have cleaned the project, and always build with clean flag

Comment: aka-one: I cannot post the pom (long story). Is there something specific you're looking for?

Comment: Gerold: Yes, I have refreshed the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix:** Eclipse needs to be launched from command line in order for PATH and other Env Vars to be picked up

**Steps:**

1. Created a new script called eclipseLauncher and made it executable (chmod 755)

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   /Applications/eclipse/jee-2018-09/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse &
   ```
2. Turned script into an app:

   a. Create an AppleScript (save as type .app) that points to the launcher script…

   ```
   do shell script "open /Applications/eclipse/scripts/eclipseLauncher"
   ```

   b. This app can then be moved to the dock and executed from there

NOTE: The app executes a script rather than directly issuing the commands. When I simply ran the command from the app, I could not get the terminal window to close after Eclipse was launched. Only by invoking the script could I get it to work like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate and delete  `.m2/repository` local repository. It should solve the problem !

Comment: I have deleted and repulled the .m2 repo a couple of times... no dice.

Comment: I have tried a clean install. I went so far as to reinstall Java, Maven, Eclipse, and re-import all files from git fresh.

Comment: Could you edit your post and post your POM file content ?

Comment: Issmeil: I cannot post the pom. Is there something specific you're looking for? NOTE: compilation works fine outside of Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Java 8, in your pom.xml, try adding this:

```
<properties>
 <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
 <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```

Or configure in plugin:

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>your maven compiler plugin version</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: I the pom already contains the <plugin> config above. I tried adding the properties, but that did not help either.